# appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1 conflicts with gms:play-services:11.0.2

Tags: android, versions

Below is my gradle file screen shot.[image: Gradle Screenshot]

Error that am getting is[image: Error Screenshot]

I know this is mismatch between versions and we have to use same versions for all support libaries.I also added **classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'**. But this doesn't helps. How to solve this?

Comment: use stable `build:gradle:2.3.3` & `buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"`

Comment: Tried.. But sorry doesn't helps

Comment: add output for `gradlew app:dependencies`. Also latest support libraries have version 26.0.0-beta2, not 26.0.0-alpha1

Comment: @Siva did you find the solution?

Comment: No. try to degrade the appcompat version and Play service version